# find a div by classname and replace it with a div based on onclick - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, toggle, show-hide

There are 8 divs and an empty div. Also there are 8 checkboxes. Initially 4 divs are displayed and the remaining are `display:none` and 4 checkboxes are checked and remaining are uncheked

The Fiddle link is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pssmjsvy/4/)
This is my code

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="empty" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div class="content div_box_1">
       <div class="box " style="background:black;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content div_box_2">
       <div class="box " style="background:blue;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content div_box_3">
       <div class="box " style="background:yellow;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content div_box_4">
       <div class="box " style="background:orange;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content div_box_5">
       <div class="box " style="background:pink; display:none;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content div_box_6">
       <div class="box " style="background:indigo; display:none;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content div_box_7">
       <div class="box " style="background:red; display:none;"></div>
</div>  
<div class="content div_box_8">
    <div class="box " style="background:skyblue; display:none;"></div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="checks">
 <input type="checkbox" name="box1" checked value="1" class="css-checkbox"/>black
<input type="checkbox" name="box2" checked value="2" class="css-checkbox"/>blue
<input type="checkbox" name="box3" checked value="3" class="css-checkbox"/>yellow
<input type="checkbox" name="box4" checked value="4" class="css-checkbox"/>orange
<input type="checkbox" name="box5" value="5" class="css-checkbox"/>pink
<input type="checkbox" name="box6" value="6" class="css-checkbox"/>indigo
<input type="checkbox" name="box7" value="7" class="css-checkbox"/>red
<input type="checkbox" name="box8" value="8" class="css-checkbox"/>sky-blue
```

When I uncheck any of these 4 checked boxes the respective div must hide and the `class=empty` div must be shown eg if I uncheck checkbox with `value=2` then div with `class="div_box_2` must be hidden and in that place div with `class=empty` must be displayed and again when checkbox with `value=5 or value=6 or value=7 or value=8` is checked then the div with `class=empty` must be hide and the corresponding div with `class=div_box_5 or class=div_box_6 or class=div_box_7 or class=div_box_8` must be displayed in the place of empty div.

Its like removing a div and putting a default div in that place and when again some other div is to be displayed then that div must be displayed in the place of default div

How is this possible?
Please anyone help.
Thank you in advance

Comment: This is definitely possible, although could you please add the code you've written yourself to attempt to solve the issue. At the moment this looks more like a job advert on a freelancing website.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have added the fiddle code in the above query. Anyways http://jsfiddle.net/pssmjsvy/4/ you can find the code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

JSfiddle: [click](http://jsfiddle.net/pssmjsvy/13/)

I changed a few thing:

- I removed your style from your HTML and put it in your CSS;
- You want to replace the divs so there is no need to hide any;

Let me explain the JS:

```
var divs = [];
divs.push('<div class="content" id="empty">' +
          '<div class="box div_box_0 empty"></div>' +
          '</div>');
$('.box').each(function (index) {
    divs[index+1] = $(this).parent();
    $(this).parent().remove();
});

var selected = [];
var max_boxes = 4;
$('.css-checkbox').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked') && selected.length < max_boxes) {
        selected.push(divs[selected.length + 1]);
    } else {
        $(this).attr('checked', false);
    }
});

while (selected.length < 4) {
    selected.push(divs[0]);
}

for (var i in selected) {
    $('.container').append(selected[i]);
}

$(".css-checkbox").click(function(){
    if ($('.css-checkbox:checked').length > 4) {
        $(this).attr('checked', false);
    } else {
        var cval = $(this).val();
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked');

        if (checked) {
            var empty = $.inArray(divs[0], selected);
            selected[empty] = divs[cval];
            $('#empty').replaceWith(divs[cval]);
        } else {
            var filled = $.inArray(divs[cval], selected);
            selected[filled] = divs[0];
            $('.container').find(divs[cval]).replaceWith(divs[0]);
        }
    }
});
```

First I create an array with the divs so you can place and replace them. The empty div has to be put in manually, since you want this one more than once. In the array you get a reference to the element. Next i remove each div out of your html.

Next I get the selected boxes and put the div by value in the selected array. After that I append the first 4 selected divs to the container.

The click function checks if there are 4 boxes clicked, when you click on a 5th one it removes the check immediately. Next there is a check to see if you checked or unchecked the checkbox. When you check it, replaces the first empty div with the selected div. If you uncheck it replaces the selected div with an empty div.

Comment: its not about changing the colors. It is about replacing the divs. I just took the colors to differentiate the divs

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a empty container is each of the content element. You can use a script to add it

```
//add an empty container to all content elements
$('.container .content').append('<div class="empty" style="display:none;"></div>');
$("input.css-checkbox:checkbox").click(function () {
    var cval = $(this).val();
    var $div = $(".div_box_" + this.value).slideToggle("fast");
    $div.next()[this.checked ? 'slideUp' : 'slideDown']("fast");
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kw2qkzh2/)

Comment: In your code the div id being displayed at the end, but it must be replaced where in the place of empty div

Comment: sorry! what I mean to say is In your code the div after checking the box is being displayed at the end, but it must be displayed in the place of empty div

Comment: uncheck black, white is displayed in the place of black and then check pink, pink must be displayed in the place of  white. Did you get my point?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/pssmjsvy/5/)

```
$(function() {
    var selectCheckBox = $(".checks input:checkbox")
    $(selectCheckBox).click(function() {
        var checkingValue = $(this).val()
        if(checkingValue == 1){
            $('.div_box_1').toggle();
        }
        else if(checkingValue == 2){
            $('.div_box_2').toggle();
        }
        else if(checkingValue == 3){
            $('.div_box_3').toggle();
        }
        else if(checkingValue == 4){
            $('.div_box_4').toggle();
        }
    })
    var selectHiddenChecks = $('.checks input:checkbox')
    $(selectHiddenChecks).click(function() {
        var checkingValue = $(this).val();
        if(checkingValue == 5) {
            $('.div_box_5').toggle();
        }
        else if(checkingValue == 6) {
            $('.div_box_6').toggle();
        }
        else if(checkingValue == 7) {
            $('.div_box_7').toggle();
        }
        else if(checkingValue == 8) {
            $('.div_box_8').toggle();
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: In your code the div id being displayed at the end, but it must be replaced where in the place of empty div

Comment: @rji rji, did not understand your comment.

Comment: sorry! what I mean to say is In your code the div after checking the box is being displayed at the end, but it must be displayed in the place of empty div